# Can a C# desktop application use UWP components?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp, c++-cx

I have a C++ library with a C++/CX wrapper. Can I reference the wrapper in a C# desktop project and use it?

I tried adding a reference the usual way. I can select the project and the reference will be added, but it has a yellow exclamation mark. IntelliSense does work and it compiles fine, but when I run it, I get a `TypeLoadException` indicating that the Windows Runtime type could not be found - even when I manually copy the dll there.

There are [some articles](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToCallWinRTAPIsInWindows8FromCDesktopApplicationsWinRTDiagram.aspx) explaining how to set up something similar with Windows 8 projects, but I haven't gotten the Windows tab to appear like that with my project.

Comment: That's a different situation, using a component from native Win32 code, whereas I want to use it from the CLR.

Comment: Win32 vs. CLR doesn't affect this. Custom Windows Runtime Components are supported only in Windows Runtime apps, not in desktop apps, for the reasons Raman explained in the other thread

Comment: That makes it clear then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Rob already commented, there is no way to use custom winrt components from a desktop .NET app (at least there is no way to do it now...).

But you can use C++ (not C++/CX!) directly in a .NET application via PInvoke, or C++/CLI

See this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/403285/P-Invoke-Tutorial-Basics-Part

Comment: I believe that Rob's comment refers to a different setup (Win32 vs CLR). P/Invoke is a great feature, but it only lets you use C++ code exposed through a C API. C++/CLI sounds like a good option; is that supported in both desktop and Windows Runtime .NET apps?